# Do a periodic task with a random interval in a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, random, scheduler, intervals

As the title says, I was wondering if there were any smart way to implement a random interval event that can go and do it's thing while main() does something else. Should I use scheduler for this or threading? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended to be a database of questions and answers for programmers who may be stuck on a particular technical problem. Your question appears to be more of a "I need to write some code to perform this task, but I don't know where to start". It's very specific, and unlikely to help others in the future. This, unfortunately, is not a good fit for SO. Please may I suggest that you take a look at [ask]. If you have already made an attempt at coding this yourself, then please show your efforts and tell us how it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could make a while loop timer for one thread:

Something like:

```
while True:
    Run_Something = rand.randrange(0,1)
    if Run_Something == 1:
        threaded_function()
```

Call break when thread is completed. Not 100% sure if this was what you were looking for but I hope I helped!